# Stop downloading stream on MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a MPMoviePlayerController, in which I open a movie stream located on Amazon S3. Now, I am calling `[[self moviePlayerController] prepareToPlay];` once the stream URL is set so that the user can see the first frame and the movie is ready to play whenever the user wants to. This is done in viewDidLoad.

However, when I do a "prepareToPlay", it actually goes and keep downloading the movie stream. I don't want that because it uses a lot of bandwidth for nothing on my servers if the user doesn't actually play it fully. Is there a way to just load the first second or so?